# Как побороть ошибку с file_get_contents failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 — https youtube?

Tags: php, youtube-api

Есть код:

```php
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos';
$cn_match = 'www.googleapis.com';
// $url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/';
// $cn_match = 'stackoverflow.com';

$data = array (     
  'key' => $api_key,               
  'part' => 'snippet',
  'id' => $video_id
);

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
  'http' => array( // text/plain
    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
    'method'  => 'GET', 
    'content' => http_build_query($data)                
  )
  , 'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => true,
    'cafile' => '/SRV/php721/extras/ssl/' . "cacert.pem",
    'ciphers' => 'HIGH:TLSv1.2:TLSv1.1:TLSv1.0:!SSLv3:!SSLv2',
    'CN_match' => $cn_match,
    'disable_compression' => true,
  )
);

$scu = $url . '?' . http_build_query($data);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
//$response = file_get_contents($scu);
//echo Debug::d($context);
//echo $scu; 
echo Debug::d($response);
```

Его выполнение приводит к ошибке:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in C:\SRV\vhosts\test.loc\html\tmp\youtube-api\ex1\t1.php on line 67
```

или попросту `HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request`.

Если делать с помощью cURL, например, вот так:

```php
$curlSession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=$video_id&key=$api_key");
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$jsonData = json_decode(curl_exec($curlSession));
curl_close($curlSession);

echo Debug::d($jsonData);
```

ошибок не возникает. Однако, как заставить заработать первоначальный код?

Comment: А почему не использовать CURL? данный метод более качественный(профессиональный) чем просто  file_get_contents

Comment: Вопрос конечно интересный, однако, отчего же этот вариант с file_get_contents не работает?

Comment: Youtube проверяет множество данных в заголовке при запросе. Возможно при запросе через file_get_contents что то не так в заголовках, вот и сервер отвечает ошибкой 400. a CURL изначально(дефолтно) имеет кучу стандартных параметров, которые отправляются с запросом.

Comment: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Required parameter: part",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Required parameter: part"
 }
}
говорит что нету параметра part, хотя он есть, но почему то к запросу не присоединяется

как все таки их присоединить?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема не в самой функции **file_get_contents**, а в том что сервер возвращает HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request. При этом он обычно сообщает, что именно ему в запросе не нравится. Но чтобы увидеть этот ответ, надо чтобы **file_get_contents** игнорировала статусы с ошибкой. Для этого надо добавить

```
$options['http']['ignore_errors'] = 1;
```

и тогда в `$response` будет актуальный ответ сервера.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел решение, которое не использует курл, но использует fopen

```
$scu = $url . '?' . http_build_query($data);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'max_redirects' => '0',
        'ignore_errors' => '1',        
    )
    , 'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => true,
        'cafile' => '/SRV/php721/extras/ssl/' . "cacert.pem",
        'ciphers' => 'HIGH:TLSv1.2:TLSv1.1:TLSv1.0:!SSLv3:!SSLv2',
        'CN_match' => $cn_match,
        'disable_compression' => true,
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$stream = fopen($scu, 'r', false, $context);

// информация о заголовках, а также
// метаданные о потоке
echo Debug::d(stream_get_meta_data($stream),'stream_get_meta_data($stream)');

// актуальная информация по ссылке $url
echo Debug::d(stream_get_contents($stream),'stream_get_contents($stream)');
fclose($stream);
```

также тут можно увидеть возникающие ошибки